# How to delete a Tkinter widget placement?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have buttons that won't go away. I wrote an absolute location of the buttons and it won't go away when I try to forget it. I managed to make it disappear with writing the absolute location of the button to the coordinate outside the window. How to make it go away with the delete function?

This is what I have

```
from tkinter import*

def delete():
    button1.pack_forget()
    button2.pack_forget()

gui =Tk()
gui.geometry("250x500")

button1 = Button(gui, text="1", command=delete, pady= 15, padx= 20)
button1.pack(pady= 5, padx= 20)
button1.place(x=85, y=60)
button2 = Button(gui, text="2", pady= 15, padx= 20)
button2.pack(pady= 5, padx= 20)
button2.place(x=63, y=120)

gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `place_forget()` instead of `pack_forget()`. You may also remove the `pack()` calls. In your example, calling *place* is negating the *pack* call. That's why `pack_forget()` will not work. The button ceased to be *packed* the instant it was *placed*.

```
button1.pack(...)  # do it this way
button1.place(...) # nevermind, do it this way
```

**example:**

```
from tkinter import *

def delete():
    button1.place_forget()
    button2.place_forget()

gui =Tk()
gui.geometry("250x500")

button1 = Button(gui, text="1", command=delete, pady= 15, padx= 20)
button1.place(x=85, y=60)
button2 = Button(gui, text="2", pady= 15, padx= 20)
button2.place(x=63, y=120)

gui.mainloop()
```

Tkinter has 3 geometry methods ~ *place, pack, and grid.* Only one geometry method is required, per widget, but combining the *grid* **or** *pack* method with *place* is allowed. However, that combination is intended to allow you to **alternatively** *pack* **or** *place* widgets simultaneously within one container. In other words, some of the widgets are *packed*, and some of them are *placed*, within one container. None of the widgets are both *packed* and *placed*.

Determining which to use is simple. If you want to "dock" a widget to one or more of it's parent's edges use *pack*. If you need a table layout use *grid*. If you need arbitrary positioning use *place*.

Comment: We can use *place* together with *grid* or *pack*. But *pack* cannot be used with *grid* or *grid* with *pack*.